# Composer Autoload not working after deployment

Tags: php, github, composer-php, autoload

I am in the midst of learning how to better maintain the code that I write. I have two projects that I am currently working on - both are in development and both are pushed to GitHub.

I am trying to include the one project in the other (by declaring it a dependency in the one project's composer.json file) - but after it is included, it is missing the proper autoload configurations.

I'll explain a little better: Project A's composer.json file has an autoload line for "psr-4" mapping the namespace to the "src" directory - all is good and working after I run:

```
composer install
```

I am then able to include the /vendor/autoload.php file and immediately start working with the project. When I look at the generated "autoload_psr4.php" file in that project's vendor directory, I can see the array contains a reference for the mapped namespace / directory per the composer.json file.

The problem comes when I try to include Project A within Project B as a dependency - everything looks to work after running the composer install - the vendor directory is created and the files are copied there - however when I look at the generated "autoload_psr4.php" file in project B it is missing the mapped namespace / directory per Project A's composer.json file.

Can someone point me in the direction for what I might be missing to get the autoload line to carry over into Project B?

Here's the two composer.json files:

Project A:

```
{
    "name": "jfreynik/hydra-net",
    "description": "Network classes for the Hydra framework.",
    "type": "library",
    "keywords": [ "http", "net", "rest" ],
    "license": "MIT",

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "hydra\\net\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Project B:

```
{
    "name": "jfreynik/simple-mvc",
    "description": "A pretty simple MVC framework for building websites.",
    "type": "framework",
    "keywords": [ "MVC", "Website Framework" ],
    "license": "MIT",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jfreynik/hydra-net",
                "version":"*-dev",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/jfreynik/hydra-net.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jfreynik/hydra-net": "*-dev"
    },
    "minumum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was including Project A into Project B as a "package". I believe "packages" are not scanned for their contained composer.json files. (please correct me if I'm wrong) - by changing Project B's composer.json file to reference Project A as "vcs" then the autoloading works again. - Here is the adjusted composer.json file for Project B.

```
{
    "name": "jfreynik/simple-mvc",
    "description": "A pretty simple little MVC framework for building websites.",
    "type": "framework",
    "keywords": [ "MVC", "Website Framework" ],
    "license": "MIT",

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/jfreynik/hydra-net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jfreynik/hydra-net": "dev-master"
    },
    "minumum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I really had trouble finding working examples as I am really just starting to use composer and prior to this had only included professional packages from packagist. I have much to learn (even in regard to terminology) - so if anyone can add additional relevant information for the proper way to include 1 development project in another I will accept your answer.